# Twig Runtime Error: Impossible to invoke a method ("test") on a string variable

Tags: symfony, twig

I have the following twig template (the code is in the same file):

```
{% macro renderJob(fields) %}
    // renders the job UI block, but I've removed it for simplicity
    Hello world.
{% endmacro %}
{% block _jobs_widget %}
    <div id="jobsContainer">
        {% for fields in form.children %}
            {% dump fields %}
            {{ _self.renderJob(fields) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

For some reason, after upgrading to `twig/twig = v2.1.0` I'm receiving the follwing error:

> Impossible to invoke a method ("renderJob") on a string variable ("@AppBundle/Jobs/form/job.html.twig").

I have been trying to figure out what's causing this without any luck. This used to work just fine in `1.3.x`. The `fields` variable contains the proper data, but it appears it can't pass it to the `renderJob` macro or it can't find the macro (which is kind of odd)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried the following ?

```
{% import _self as renderJobMacro %}

{% macro renderJob(fields) %}
    // renders the job UI block, but I've removed it for simplicity
    Hello world.
{% endmacro %}

{% block _jobs_widget %}
    <div id="jobsContainer">
        {% for fields in form.children %}
            {{ renderJobMacro.renderJob(fields) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks! It apperas, as @Maulik said, that `_self` reference is deprecated in Twig 2.0. For this to work, though, I had to `import` the template inside the `_jobs_widget` block. Thanks!

Comment: When I created an hierarchical list, and called the macro several times, I had to import the _self before each time:    
    
`{% for child in level.children %}
       {% import _self as template %}
       {{ template.display_tree(child) }}
{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 2):

I think _self is depricated from twigg 2.0, May be you need to check without `_self`.

Check `{{ renderJob(fields) }}` instead of `{{ _self.renderJob(fields) }}`